# 2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0 "Internal error/check (Not system error)"

Tags: ssh, mysql, firewall, mysql-workbench

I have these users in MySQL

| User | Host |
| --- | --- |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost |
| mysql.session | localhost |
| mysql.sys | localhost |
| root | localhost |

I want to connect to it remotely from my mac via SSH

I can't connect. I kept getting

> 2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0 "Internal error/check (Not system error)"

I know if I did add this record below.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| root | % |

I will be able to connect, but it seems not very secure to do that. I thought we can connect to our database via SSH. Please correct me what I did wrong.

I don't have anything set in the local firewalls in my server, but I do that have networking firewall rules at Digital Ocean.

**All rules configured**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A late answer, but I got the same issue.
The problem was that I was trying to connect to a mariadb server with a mysql client (mysql-client-8.0).
Using the mariadb client (1:10.6.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) solved this issue.
Hope it can help.